# Find a node/page in admin by looking at the code

Tags: nodes

I'm very new to Drupal, and I want to edit some text on the front page. In the **page.tpl.php**, I have this code `print render($page['content'])`, if I remove it, then the area that I want to edit with is disappeared from the front page, so I know this is the right part, but how can I find out which page, content, or node is being called in the backend?

I'm using Drupal 7.55.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and enabling Webprofiler. It gives you a lot of useful meta information about the current request, including the controller and route used:

[image]

Comment: How do you enable Webprofiler on D7? I know in D8 it's a module that comes with Devel, but [I don't see it as a module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/devel/tree/?h=7.x-1.x) in D7.

Comment: I actually have the same question. I'm using drupal 7.55 and I installed and enable module Devel, but I don't see Webprofiler.

Comment: The question wasn't about Drupal 7 until after I answered it. The web profiler is from Symfony, so not available in Drupal 7.